# ThreadLocalRandom is undefined in beanshell script

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Simple bean shell pre-processor is added to test plan as follows:

[image]

However, on running the pre-processor it errors out in the logviewer stating the following:

```
2023-07-01 21:45:18,461 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.util.*; // log.info(String.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom)); . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: current() on undefined variable or class name: ThreadLocalRandom
2
```

Using jmeter 5.5. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your import is incorrect. The code would be

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

log.info ("id: {}", ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 599))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're really going to use this way of generating a random number you need to add a relevant import statement:

   ```
   import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
   ```
2. The easier way would be going for [RandomUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html) class:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

   var id = RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 600)
   ```
3. In general [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating [as Groovy has much better performance comparing to other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter).
4. And last but not the least you don't need to do any scripting at all, you can achieve the same using JMeter's built-int [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random):

   ```
   ${__Random(1,600,id)}
   ```